# Scheme One-Over-twenty-two function

Tags: scheme, helper

I wrote a function to compute the value of 1/22 as follows: (I know that scheme already can compute the value of 1/22 as a calculator can)

```
(define (one-over-twenty-two n)
 (if (<= n 1) 
  0
  (if (= 0 (modulo n 2)) 
      (+ (* (/ 1 (expt 10 n)) 4.0) (one-over-twenty-two (- n 1)))
      (+ (* (/ 1 (expt 10 n)) 5) (one-over-twenty-two (- n 1))))))
```

This function works as intended. I however, want to write this function using a helper function and I am stuck. My code is as follows:

```
(define (one-over-22 n)
 (define (one-over-22-h next k)
  (cond ((= k n) 0)
       ((<= k 1) 0)
       ((= 4 next)(* (/ 1 (expt 10 n)) 4.0)(+ k 1) (+ next 1))
       ((= 5 next)(* (/ 1 (expt 10 n)) 5.0)(+ k 1) (- next 1))))
(one-over-22-h 4 0) (one-over-22 (- n 1)))
```

I believe I am ending up with infinite recursion here, but I can't tell. Also, should I be summing within my helper function or should I do that in the body of the main function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in the second version of the function:

- The iteration variable in the helper function is `k`, `n` should not appear in the code
- The conditions are not the same as in the original function
- You're incorrectly calling both the helper function *and* the `one-over-22` function, the idea here is that the helper takes care of the iteration, and `one-over-22` just passes the appropriate initial values to the helper
- The initial value of `next` depends on whether `n` is even or odd, it's not always `4`

This should fix the problems found, compare with your code to see where the errors were:

```
(define (one-over-22 n)
  (define (one-over-22-h next k)
    (cond ((<= k 1) 0)
          ((= next 4)
           (+ (* (/ 1 (expt 10 k)) next)
              (one-over-22-h (+ next 1) (- k 1))))
          ((= next 5)
           (+ (* (/ 1 (expt 10 k)) next)
              (one-over-22-h (- next 1) (- k 1))))))
  (one-over-22-h (if (even? n) 4.0 5.0) n))
```